# bash: using rename to left pad filenames with a zero under when their prefix is too short

Tags: bash, rename

I'm using a naming convention with number prefixes to track some files.  But I am running out with 2-digit prefix.  So, instead of `11.abc 12.def` I want to move to `011.abc 012.def`.  I already have some `013.xxx 014.yyy`.

Trying this in an empty directory:

`touch 11.abc 12.def 013.xxx 014.yyy`

`ls -1` gives:

```
013.xxx
014.yyy
11.abc
12.def
```

Try #1:

This should match anything that starts with 2 digits, but not 3.

`rename -n 's/^\d\d[^\d]/0$1/' *`

Now I was kind of hoping that `$1` would hold the match, like `11`, with 0$1 giving me `011`.

No such luck:

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 2) line 1.
'11.abc' would be renamed to '0abc'
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at (eval 2) line 1.
'12.def' would be renamed to '0def'
```

On the positive side, it's willing to leave 013 and 014 alone.

Try #2 `rename -n 's/^\d\d[^\d]/0/' *`

```
'11.abc' would be renamed to '0abc'
'12.def' would be renamed to '0def'
```

Since this is regex based, can I somehow save the match group `11` and `12`?

If I can't use rename I'll probably write a quick Python script.  Don't want to loop with `mv` on it.

And, actually, my naming covention is 2-3 digits followed by a dot, so this is a good match too.

`rename -n 's/^\d\d\./<whatever needs to go here>/' *`

For what it's worth, I am using the Homebrew version of rename, as I am on a mac.

Comment: Try `rename -n 's/^(\d\d)[^\d]/0\1/'` capture group and backreference

Comment: No luck.  It says `\1 better written as $1 at (eval 2) line 1.`.  When I put in `$1` instead it doesn't show it doing anything so it may not be implementing some of the regex stuff.

Comment: What OS and version?

Comment: Try using a capture group

Comment: @bishop macOS Sierra

Comment: @JLPeyret Which `rename` command are you using? It doesn't come standard in macOS, and there are at least two different programs with that name that work significantly differently from each other.

Comment: @GordonDavisson  the one I got from homebrew.

Comment: It seems a pity that you have ruled out using a loop and `mv` because this straightforward code seems to do precisely what you need: `for f in [0-9][0-9].* ; do mv "$f" "0$f"; done`.

Comment: @pjh  if you write it up, I'll upvote it.  UtLox's solution works, but I have been using yours yesterday and it works, despite it not being `rename`-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
rename 's/^(\d{2}\..*)/0$1/' *
```

Comment: that works.  Now, all I need to figure out is the difference between this and the other 5 things I tried ;-)  I suppose it has to do with the precise use of the capture groups syntax.

Comment: Ah, I think I see... the capture group `(\d{2}\..*)` basically matches the whole file name.  and puts it in `$1`.  which I can then left-pad with 0.

Answer (score 1):

`rename` is problematic because it's not part of POSIX (so it isn't normally available on many Unix-like systems), and there are two very different forms of it in widespread use.  See [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/264812) for more information.

This Bash code does the renaming with `mv` (which is part of POSIX):

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob  # Patterns that match nothing expand to nothing.

for f in [0-9][0-9].* ; do
    mv "$f" "0$f"
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` is to prevent problems if the code is run in a directory that has no files that need to be renamed.  If `nullglob` isn't enabled the code would try to rename a file called '[0-9][0-9].*', which would have unwanted consequences whether or not such a file existed.